# Flattening/normalizing a deeply nested dictionary with duplicate keys

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, normalization

I am trying to flatten my deeply nested dictionary with duplicate keys so that finally I can create a pandas dataframe. I have tried several steps with normalization but I can't figure it out.

```
from pandas import json_normalize

data = {
   "test": [
       {
           "landje": "ES",
           "broodje": [
               {"coupon": "abcde", "aap": [{"type": "dirk", "dirk_code": "1234"}], "days_due": ["1"]},
               {"coupon": "zxcv", "aap": [{"type": "dirk", "dirk_code": "2345"}], "days_due": ["2"]}
           ]
       },
       {
           "landje": "FR",
           "broodje": [
               {"coupon": "ergd", "aap": [{"type": "dirk", "dirk_code": "4567"}], "days_due": ["3"]},
               {"coupon": "tygh", "aap": [{"type": "dirk", "dirk_code": "7789"}], "days_due": ["4"]}
           ]
       }
   ]
}

def flatten_dict(d, parent_key='', sep='_'):
   items = []
   if isinstance(d, dict):
       for k, v in d.items():
           new_key = f"{parent_key}{sep}{k}" if parent_key else k
           if isinstance(v, dict):
               items.extend(flatten_dict(v, new_key, sep=sep).items())
           elif isinstance(v, list):
               for i, item in enumerate(v):
                   items.extend(flatten_dict(item, f"{new_key}", sep=sep).items())
           else:
               items.append((new_key, v))
   return dict(items)

# Extract the unique keys from the data dictionary
keys = data.keys()

for key in keys:
   flat_dicts = [flatten_dict(item) for item in data[key]]
   for flat_dict in flat_dicts:
       print(flat_dict)
```

This gives me the following output:

```
{'landje': 'ES', 'broodje_coupon': 'zxcv', 'broodje_aap_type': 'dirk', 'broodje_aap_dirk_code': '2345'}
{'landje': 'FR', 'broodje_coupon': 'tygh', 'broodje_aap_type': 'dirk', 'broodje_aap_dirk_code': '7789'}
```

I  am missing two rows to fill my dataframe with.

I would like my final result to look like the example shown below. The column names are not that important but I want to extract all the information.

What is another way than flattening the dictionary but using for example pd.json_normalize?

I did not get that without hardcoding the record_path or meta.

```
          landje          broodje_coupon          broodje_aap_type          broodje_aap_dirk_code          broodje_aap_days_due
0          ES                 abcde                      dirk                          1234                         1
1          ES                 zxcv                       dirk                          2345                         2
2          FR                 ergd                       dirk                          4567                         3
3          FR                 tygh                       dirk                          7789                         4
```

Comment: A Python dictionary, by definition, cannot have duplicate keys

Comment: Please use standard spelling & punctuation. Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally just flatten this by hand.

```py
import pandas

data = {
   "test": [
       {
           "landje": "ES",
           "broodje": [
               {"coupon": "abcde", "aap": [{"type": "dirk", "dirk_code": "1234"}], "days_due": ["1"]},
               {"coupon": "zxcv", "aap": [{"type": "dirk", "dirk_code": "2345"}], "days_due": ["2"]}
           ]
       },
       {
           "landje": "FR",
           "broodje": [
               {"coupon": "ergd", "aap": [{"type": "dirk", "dirk_code": "4567"}], "days_due": ["3"]},
               {"coupon": "tygh", "aap": [{"type": "dirk", "dirk_code": "7789"}], "days_due": ["4"]}
           ]
       }
   ]
}

data_flattened = [
    {
        "landje": row["landje"],
        "broodje_coupon": broodje["coupon"],
        "broodje_aap_type": aap["type"],
        "broodje_aap_dirk_code": aap["dirk_code"],
        "broodje_aap_days_due": days_due,
    }
    for row in data["test"]
    for broodje in row["broodje"]
    for aap, days_due in zip(broodje["aap"], broodje["days_due"])
]

print(pandas.DataFrame(data_flattened))
```

That should give you:

```
  landje broodje_coupon broodje_aap_type broodje_aap_dirk_code broodje_aap_days_due
0     ES          abcde             dirk                  1234                    1
1     ES           zxcv             dirk                  2345                    2
2     FR           ergd             dirk                  4567                    3
3     FR           tygh             dirk                  7789                    4
```